# Catkin_make a package with dynamic_reconfigure for Python node

Tags: python, catkin, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm struggling compiling a catkin package with a Python node using dynamic_reconfigure.

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(motors)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
  dynamic_reconfigure
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  MotorPower.msg
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)

generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
  cfg/pig.cfg
)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS rospy std_msgs
)

add_dependencies(pid ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)
```

And this is my package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>motors</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The motors package</description>

  <maintainer email="ubuntu@todo.todo">ubuntu</maintainer>

  <license>todo</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>dynamic_reconfigure</build_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>dynamic_reconfigure</run_depend>

  <export>
  </export>
</package>
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the error:

> CMake Error at motors/CMakeLists.txt:29 (add_dependencies):
> Cannot add target-level dependencies to non-existent target "pid".

> The add_dependencies works for top-level logical targets created by the
> add_executable, add_library, or add_custom_target commands.  If you want to
> add file-level dependencies see the DEPENDS option of the add_custom_target
> and add_custom_command commands.

How can I introduce the "pid" node (located in the file scripts/pid.py) as a target?
add_executable and add_library only seem to work for C nodes.

Or is there any self-containing example project or tutorial?
Currently I'm following the [default ROS tutorial on dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile#dynamic_reconfigure.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile.2BAC8-catkin.Use_the_cfg_File).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228687/catkin_make-a-package-with-dynamic_reconfigure-for-python-node/) by [Falko](https://answers.ros.org/users/23523/falko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik, you don't need to `add_dependencies(..)` for a Python node. You won't be compiling the Python node, so it won't need the dyn cfg files at compile time. `add_dependencies(..)` is used to make sure dyn cfg is generated *before* C/C++ nodes are compiled that include the headers.

Also: note that your DynCfg file is called `cfg/piG.cfg`, while your `add_dependencies(..)` statement references something called `piD`.

And: see [catkin 0.6.17 documentation - Dynamic reconfiguration](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/dynamic_reconfiguration.html) for documentation on what to do for Dynamic Reconfigure (but again: some steps are for C++ only).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Falko](https://answers.ros.org/users/23523/falko/) on 2016-03-10**:
Oh wow, @gvdhoorn! It just was the typo "pig" instead of "pid"! Thanks so much! Now it's compiling (without add_dependencies). :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-10**:
Good to hear. Glad the world still makes sense :).

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-10**:
If your problem is solved, please check mark the answer.